# I want to display a Snack Bar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the function that is being called on a button click.

```
handleClick() {
        var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
        x.className = "show";
        setTimeout(function () {
            x.className = x
                .className
                .replace("show", "");
        }, 3000);
        return (
            <div id="snackbar">DONE</div>
        )
    }
```

This is my onClick `onClick={this.handleClick}`

It shows me an error that"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null" 
What am I doing wrong. All the help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example shows `onClick={this.handleClick()}` but it should be `onClick={this.handleClick}`. Change that and if you still have problems update your question.

Comment: Still Gives Error

Comment: updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null"

Means that you are trying to access the classname property in a null variable.

If `var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");` has not results, it will return null, and x will be equal to null.
Add console.log(x) after `var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");` so you can test if it comes from here.

It can be caused by:

```
Invalid HTML syntax (some tag is not closed or similar error)
Duplicate IDs - there are two HTML DOM elements with the same ID
Maybe element you are trying to get by ID is created dynamically (loaded by ajax or created by script)?
```

Comment: console log is giving null.

Comment: It means that there is no html element with the ID "snackbar" when getElementById is run

Comment: You should check the id of the element you want to select, and maybe use getElementByClass or getElementByTagName

Comment: div id="snackbar">DONE</div>

Comment: Wouldnt this work if i return it in the same function

Comment: Maybe the result is null because there are more than one elements with the same id, the element is not initialized or the html is invalid